# How to capture the image inside the bounding box for object detection app using TensorflowLite

Tags: java, android-studio, machine-learning, object-detection, tensorflow-lite

I am a beginner in developing android apps. Currently, as a school project, I am working on a mask detection app using TensorFlowLite in Android Studio. I want to know how to capture image who are not wearing mask and save the image which is from the bounding box either in an internal storage or send to a database. Anyone have any idea on how to go about doing this? Sample code will be much appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: Unfortunately you are asking to broadly. Ask a question about a specific problem, tell us what you already tried and someone will be happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you have the object detector that returns a bounding box. If that's the case, then try cropping the image using the bounding box. If the image is a numpy array, then you can crop it using array slicing like this.

```
(x1, y1, x2, y2) = detected_bbox
cropped_image = input_image[int(y1):int(y2), int(x1):int(x2)]
```

If your question includes the object detection and database component, etc., then maybe ask several more focused questions and you'll likely get help.